# Define subpart section

Tags: sectioning

I need a section which isn’t really a part, nor a chapter. So I was trying to define a new command, \subpart, based on the \part command, but with its own numbering and which would look like this, in the middle of a new blank page:

> SUBPART ONE
>
> **Name of the subpart**

However, when I try to do so, there always are errors showing up…

My approach, based on the code from I-dont-remember-where on the web:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@subpart[#1]{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{subpart}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{subpart}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{subpart}{#1}%
    \fi
    {\parindent \z@ %\raggedright                    % Commented \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
       \Large\bfseries\hfil\partname~\thepart\hfil   %  added \hfil … \hfil for centering
       \par\nobreak
     \fi
     \huge \bfseries %
     \markboth{}{}\par}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading}
\makeatother
```

I really should learn to use LaTeX correctly…

Thank you for your help,
Sebastian

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It is probably better to use the [titlesec package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) to do this for your.  Much more is involved than defining one command `\@subpart` command.  (Your code looks like a piece of the definition of part in the `book.cls`.)

Answer (score 2):

Defining a whole new sectional unit is not a simple matter. Using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package can alleviate the job; since you didn't provide information on how entries for the subparts should look in the ToC, I chose a style between that of parts and the one for chapters; you can change this redefining appropriately `\l@subpart`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\newcommand\subpartname{Subpart}
\titleclass{\subpart}{top}[\part]
\newcounter{subpart}
\renewcommand\thesubpart{\Numberstring{subpart}}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\subpart}[display]
  {\normalsize\Huge\filcenter}{\scshape\subpartname~\thesubpart}{1em}{{\bfseries#1}\iftitlemeasuring{\def\ttl@endlongest{\clearpage}}{}}
\titlespacing*{\subpart}
  {0pt}{0em}{\pagetotal}
\makeatother

\newcommand\subpartautorefname{\subpartname}
\newcommand\subpartbreak{\cleardoublepage\mbox{}\vfil}

\assignpagestyle{\subpart}{plain}

\makeatletter
\def\toclevel@subpart{0}
\newcommand*\l@subpart[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{1em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       \large\bfseries\subpartname~#1\hfil\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
       \nobreak
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\part{Test Part One}
\subpart{Test Subpart One}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section}
\subpart{Test Subpart Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

Take into account that now the level of sectional units, from `\chapter` downwards, has decreased by one: i.e., `\part` has level `-1`, `\subpart` has level `0`, `\chapter` has level `1`, `\section` has level `2`, `\subsection` has level `3`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Gonzalo Medina's answer is nice.  However, I would like to supplement it by

1. showing how you can use the `titletoc` package to deal with the table of contents, and
2. showing how the numbering scheme can be changed so subpart and chapters include the higher level counters.

## First version

Just adding `titletoc`:

[image: Sample subpart]

with

[image: Sample table of contents]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{\part}[display]{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}%
{\partname~\thepart}{1pc}{\Huge\bfseries}

\titleclass{\subpart}{page}[\part]

\newcounter{subpart}

\renewcommand{\thesubpart}{\Alph{subpart}}
\newcommand{\subpartname}{Subpart}

\titleformat{\subpart}[display]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}%
{\subpartname~\thesubpart}{1pc}{\Huge\bfseries}

\titlespacing{\subpart}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titlecontents{subpart}[0pt]{\addvspace{1pc}\normalfont\bfseries}%
{\thecontentslabel\enspace ---\enspace\large}%
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\hspace{2em plus 1fill}\large\contentspage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Part One}

\subpart{First Subpart}

\chapter{A chapter}

\subpart{Second Subpart}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\section{Testing}

\section{TT}

\part{Part Two}

\subpart{First Subpart}

\chapter{A chapter}

\subpart{Second Subpart}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```

The main thing to note in the above is that it is necessary to redefine `part`, in order to get the table of contents features to work.  The code then

- sets up `subpart` as a subdivision directly below `part` (and so above `chapter`),
- defines the corresponding counter and the way it is printed (`\thesubpart`)
- introduces a string for the subpart name
- sets up the printing of subpart titles as displayed (so centered) block
- defines the formatting for the table of contents

## Second version

With subnumbering:

[image: New sample subpart]

with

[image: New sample table of contents]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\titleformat{\part}[display]{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}%
{\partname~\thepart}{1pc}{\Huge\bfseries}

\titleclass{\subpart}{page}[\part]

\newcounter{subpart}[part]
\numberwithin{chapter}{subpart}

\renewcommand{\thesubpart}{\thepart-\Alph{subpart}}
\newcommand{\subpartname}{Subpart}

\titleformat{\subpart}[display]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}%
{\subpartname~\thesubpart}{1pc}{\Huge\bfseries}

\titlespacing{\subpart}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titlecontents{subpart}[0pt]{\addvspace{1pc}\normalfont\bfseries}%
{\thecontentslabel\enspace ---\enspace\large}%
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\hspace{2em plus 1fill}\large\contentspage}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\addvspace{0.5pc}\normalfont\bfseries}%
{\thecontentslabel\enspace}{}{\hspace{2em plus 1fill}\contentspage}

\dottedcontents{section}[6em]{}{4em}{1pc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Part One}

\subpart{First Subpart}

\chapter{A chapter}

\subpart{Second Subpart}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\section{Testing}

\section{TT}

\part{Part Two}

\subpart{First Subpart}

\chapter{A chapter}

\subpart{Second Subpart}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```

In this case the code is the same, except for

- the `subpart` counter is now defined to be reset at each `part`
- the `chapter` counter resets at each subpart (`\numberwithin` from the AMS packages has been used for this)
- `\thesubpart` now also prins the part number
- table of contents formatting for lower levels is also redefined to allow space for the labels

Comment: Subpart title takes a whole page by itself. What should I do to write texts just after the subpart (or to write on the same page as the subpart title is printed)?. Not on the next page. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Maryà Something like `\titleclass{\subpart}{top}[\part]` gives you subparts that act more like chapters.