# Extra section between part and chapter

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I want to have an extra sectioning level under `\part{}`, say `\subpart`. It has no difference as for the location on the page or the size of the font with `\part{}` command.

I tried titlesec but I couldn't get it to work. I've read the documentation but no luck.
This is the example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
 \titleclass{\subpart}{page}[\part]
 \titleformat{\subpart}[block]{\centering\huge\bfseries}{}{10pt}{}[]
%\titlespacing*{\subpart}{}{}{}[]
\newcounter{subpart}
\renewcommand{\subpart}{\Alph{subpart}}
\begin{document}
        \part*{History}
    \subpart*{Before}
        \chapter*{1}
        \chapter*{2}
        \chapter*{3}
    \subpart*{After}
\part*{Evidence}
    \subpart*{Archeology}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: [Andrew Swann's answer for Define subpart section](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108655/3345) seems to work, except for differences in subpart page formatting. And not sure why all your divisions are starred, but titlesec recommends setting the `secnumdepth` counter to disable numbering. `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}` in Andrew's answer disables all numbering from parts on down.

Comment: Thanks, it seems a nice answer and I'll do as recommended for numbering.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Yeah it is a duplicate question but with a slightly minor difference. I really searched the site not only today but back in a month when I had the problem and because I didn't find Andrew's answer back then I postpone dealing with the problem. By the way I want the ``subpart`` command to be printed exactly the same as part. even if one changes the page size it automatically place it at the center of the page. Bernard

Comment: I don't treat "duplicate" as "bad question" or "should have searched better", but that the solutions are fundamentally the same. Assuming you can get subparts at all (Andrew's answer), formatting a subpart with titlesec is identical to formatting any other type of division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must ‘renewcommand’ `\thesubbpart`, not `\subpart`:

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{book}
\usepackage[b5paper, showframe]{geometry} \usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}

\titleclass{\subpart}{page}[\part]
\newcounter{subpart}
 \titleformat{\subpart}[block]{\centering\Huge\bfseries}{\thesubpart.}{10pt}{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\titlespacing*{\subpart}{0pt}{151pt}{12\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\thesubpart}{\Alph{subpart}}

\begin{document}

        \part*{History}
    \subpart{Before}
        \chapter*{One}
        \chapter*{Two}
        \chapter*{Three}
    \subpart{After}
\part*{Evidence}
    \subpart*{Archeology}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @bernard. my document size is b5, is there an automatic way to place in the middle of the page. I don't maybe using ``pagewidth`` and ``pageheight`` if possible. Also is there a way to retain the font attributes of the ``\part`` command. I want it to be exactly the same to part.

Comment: @nima: I've updated my answer  for the page size (with the `geometry` package) and the font size. To place it in the middle of the page, I would advise against it. It would be better to use the *golden ratio* for aesthetic reasons. Other than that, it can be done, and the simplest way to do it is by trial and errors, if you have a rule in your pdf viewer.

Comment: I'm already ok, I wonder how the original ``\part`` command do it regardless of the page size, is it simple to reproduce it for a new sectioning command or not?

Comment: It shouldn't be hard (except perhaps for some details). The layout of `part` for books can be found in `book.cls` lines `299–349` which, after some generalitiesvfor class options (`openright`, `twocolumn`), describe successively `\part` and `part*` (cf `\def@part` and `\def@spart`).